# Find continuous stochastic variable $X$ with PDF $f_X = \frac{1}{x^2}$

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, uniform-distribution

Given the uniform stochastic variable $U$ defined on the interval [0,1].
Using $U$, define a continuous stochastic variable $X$ with probability density function (PDF)
$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x^2},  & \text{for x $\geq$1} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Now I now that the uniform distribution $U$ has PDF
$$f_U(x) = \begin{cases}
1,  & \text{for x $\in$ [0,1]} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
and cumulative distribution function (CDF)
$$F_X(x) = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{for x $\leq$0} \\
x, & \text{for x $\in$ [0,1]} \\
1, & \text{for x $\geq$ 1}
\end{cases}$$

However, I have no idea on how to construct $X$ using $U$. Any idea?

Comment: This is a very well known result in the first course of simulation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling

Comment: For every $x\geqslant1$, $P(X\geqslant x)=\frac1x=P(U\leqslant\frac1x)=P(\frac1U\geqslant x)$ hence...

Comment: @Did How does $P(\frac{1}{U} > x)$ imply that $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: @Whizkid95 ?? $P(1/U>x)$ implies nothing, $P(1/U>x)$ is a number.

Comment: @Did Right, I see. But how does that help here?

Comment: @Whizkid95 This shows that $P(X>x)=P(1/U>x)$ for every $x$, hence, as requested, that $X$ and $1/U$ have the same distribution.